# Launcher opens NTFS locations under devices instead of Nautilus

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus, launcher, devices

On Ubuntu 16.04, is there a way for Launcher to open folders from NTFS partitions (which are auto-mounted) under the icon/instance of Nautilus instead of what it started doing in 16.04, i.e. instead of opening them under Devices?

What happens is that I have an NTFS partition mounted with all my data on it (I have dual boot). I have all the bookmarks and places set up in Nautilus. When I right-click the Nautilus icon (on the Launcher) and choose one of the bookmarked locations (the ones in the NTFS partition), they open as a separate Device icon on the Launcher, instead of Nautilus.

Supposedly, it's because "the file manager (Nautilus) is now integrated with Unity Launcher, so every device icon available on Unity Launcher only manages the relative window, while the Files (Nautilus) icon matches the other views. For instance, if you click on the Trash (or USB devices, etc.) icon, the Nautilus window that opens is managed from the Trash icon, and not from the Nautilus icon from the Launcher" (webupd8.com).

If you open the same location BUT through a Link placed in the Home folder, it'll run under Nautilus icon... I cannot be the only one getting annoyed by this, right?

Comment: You can probably suppress this device from showing up as separate device at all by automounting it at boot using an `/etc/fstab` entry. Not sure if you would want that.

Comment: So I did that through Disks, then select the partition, Edit Mount Options from the gear icon. The settings I have there: Automatic Mount Options - OFF;  Mount at Startup - checked; then lower in options stored in fstab: defaults. It still shows as a separate icon

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. This is really annoying.

Comment: Because of this issue, I actually switched to Windows.... Imagine that - Windows! Sad...

Comment: I am suffering from this same issue, NTFS partition mounted with /etc/fstab. This is really annoying. Is there a corresponding bug on launchpad?

Comment: To answer my own comment/question, there is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1629651

And a similar bug report has been open for 4 years (sigh).